# How do I create a junction on Win8?

Tags: windows-8, junction

I tried the following:

```
C:\Users\Chloe\Documents>dir /a "My Music"
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 808A-8F0B

 Directory of C:\Users\Chloe\Documents\My Music

File Not Found

C:\Users\Chloe\Documents>mklink /j "My Music" "c:\Users\Chloe\Music"
Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
```

`mklink`'s help shows the following:

```
C:\Users\Chloe\Documents>mklink
Creates a symbolic link.

MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target

        /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
                symbolic link.
        /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
        /J      Creates a Directory Junction.
        Link    specifies the new symbolic link name.
        Target  specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link
                refers to.
```

Comment: I see `dir /a` will display the junctions, but you can't list it by name! `dir /a "My Music"` does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete those directories in Explorer. Despite using `fsutil reparsepoint delete "My Music"`. They would not show up with `dir /a` after I 'deleted' them, but they did show up with `dir /a` before I 'deleted' them. They still showed up in Explorer after the command line 'delete'. I even rebooted and they were there. I deleted in Explorer, and re-created the junctions/links. Must be a bug in Windows.

Answer (score 4):

The junction is already there... you just did not check for it properly. Try:

```
cd C:\Users\Chloe\Documents
dir /ah "My Music*"
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't buy that. I used `dir /a` and saw it before I used `fsutil reparsepoint delete "My Music"`. /a will list all files. Just now I even listed a different hidden file and verified the H attribute with `attrib`.

Comment: The bottom line is - you used  the correct command to create a junction. The reason that the command failed is that the junction already existed. You can submit another question about "how properly check if a junction already exists"

Comment: It's a bug in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the security settings for the folder/junction in question? Microsoft uses a trick to prevent recursive linking when it comes to the junction/links created by Windows installations.

Basically, it grants `Everyone` privileges to `traverse directory` but denies `List Data` permission. The end result is that attempting to run `DIR` from the command-line on that folder will give you a "Access denied" error because you are not allowed to list the contents of that folder. So, Local Settings, for example, will work just fine if you go `cd C:\Users\you\Local Settings\Microsoft`, it'll work just fine. If you go `cd C:\Users\you\Local Settings`, you'll get an error.

Not sure if that's related, but this bit me a while back, so hopefully it can help someone.